# Scope of "use module" and associated linking error

Tags: linker, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am trying to navigate my way around fortran 90 and I have this toy example using which I would like to ask a question

```
module foo
implicit none
contains

subroutine foobar()
print *,'foobar'
end subroutine foobar
end module foo
```

Then the main program -

```
program test

use foo

real a,b,c

a = 10.
b= 10.
c= 10.
print *,'hello world'

call abc(a,b,c)
end program test  
subroutine abc(a,b,c)

call def(a,b,c)

end subroutine abc

subroutine def(a,b,c)

call foobar()
print *,'def'

end subroutine def
```

If I do not include the 'use foo' statement in subroutine def I get a linking error while linking test.o and foo.o-undefined reference. Why is that ? By declaring use foo at the 'main' level do the subroutines also not get access to the symbol foo ? 
I would  guess not based on the compiler error. So this means the only way to move forward is to include the use foo statement in every subroutine. What is the motivation behind this ?

Comment: @francescalus - question can be closed as a duplicate. Vladimir F has already explained it. I did not run a thorough check before posting this question.